# Code for A Graphical User Interface window

Tags: actionscript-3, user-interface

How would someone go about coding a 'window'? I'm starting to make a GUI, and I want to learn how to code one. One that can be skinnable, and one that actually loops and creates itself at runtime. I understand that this might be a bit vague, so I'll add details.

One that actually 'creates' itself. Most GUI tutorials I've looked on depends on an 'image' that just gets added on the screen. I want to be able to use skins in my windows. One where my 'skin' is just a collection of 'borders'. Then when I insert `window.create(50,50)` where 50,50 is my height, width, It would just create that window, following the skin.

I understand that it probably follows just like when a language draws a rectangle, it just follows a different set of rules (maybe?). However, for all my Google-fu skills I cannot find a tutorial that teaches me this.

Please Help. I didn't include the language I used as you can see, because I believe I just need to know how to create one. Anyway though, I am using Actionscript 3. A tutorial would be just fine, or even A SINGLE CLASS THAT HAS THIS FUNCTIONALITY, I'll just study the code. Or if you know one, maybe a whole book about GUI and programming it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure As3.0 GUI coding is quite troublesome. I try to Googling, but not come out well. anyway for my case, i generate using a SWC, and Class Mapping and Customizing. but i'm not sure best way. in other way i use a [bit101](http://www.minimalcomps.com/?page_id=5) library. this is gives me want **Window**, **Charts**, **Componets** easily of high abstraction. see the below image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It can be pretty hard and complicated to do, or very easy, it just depends on how flexible your solution should be. You need firstly to design a structure of your program and approach to the problem.

I like to go from the image of how it should look like from API point of view. I think I would create a GUI element like this:

```
var wholeGui:MyGUI = new MyGUI();
var window:IGuiElement = new GuiWindow(dataObject, skinObject);
wholeGui.addElement(window);
```

So what would you need?

1) Object that would manage all GUI elements. Why? Simply because your GUI elements shouldn't be destroyed by themselves if user will click "X" on your little window. The wholeGui object would manage them and listen for any events including those that would destroy them. You may consider creating custom events for interaction between the wholeGui object and your window object if this interaction is going to be complicated.

2) Interface for your GUI objects. Some problem here is that AS3 actually doesn't have interface for Sprite, and you would like to interact with it like with extended Sprite. The workaround here is to have in this interface a declaration like this:

```
function asSprite():Sprite;
```

And your implementation in GuiWindow would look like this:

```
public function asSprite():Sprite {
    return this;
}
```

And your GuiWindow class should extend Sprite of course. Then you would have access to it's Sprite properties and methods by writing for example: window.asSprite.startDrag();

This interface should give you abilities that you need to operate on your GUI element.

3) Class for your GUI element, in this example GuiWindow.

4) Class for your data that would be injected into your element. If you would load data dynamically, and from some location, you would need to deal with the situation when no data can be provided - but that logic would be inside your window.

5) Class for your skin - so you would be able to dynamically create a skin object and use it to create your window in a way you want.

That's just few thoughts to consider.

PS. It may be good idea to fill GuiWindow object with data AFTER creating it, and not in constructor, as you would be able to visualize loading process then.